# Add new column with binary (o and 1) data with t-sql based on a combination of other columns in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have requirement to insert binary code (0,1) into new column to identify same set of columns (Subject_code, Start, Organizer) in a table. Here is an example

```
ID  Subject_code    Start   Organizer   status
44297   A1           8AM       X         Open
60053   A2           4PM       y         Open
36602   B1           3PM       X         Done
57914   B1           3PM       X         Done
27464   B1           3PM       X         Open
29043   B3           8AM       Y         Open
58400   B3           8AM       Y         Done
```

And the desired outcome is shown below. 1 will be assigned to the first record of similar combination of columns (Subject_code, Start, Organizer)  and 0 for the rest of the records.

```
ID  New_Code    Subject_code    Start   Organizer   status
44297   1         A1            8AM      X          Open
60053   1         A2            4PM      y          Open
36602   1         B1            3PM      X          Done
57914   0         B1            3PM      X          Done
27464   0         B1            3PM      X          Open
29043   1         B3            8AM      Y          Open
58400   0         B3            8AM      Y          Done
```

I couldn’t come up with tsql code with the limited time I have.

Comment: what determines the order of this dataset?

Comment: More specifically, why is 36602 ID considered the "First". Why not 57914? I'm guessing it's `ORDER BY subject_code, CAST(start as <actual time>), organizer, status, id` but it's hard to solve this one without knowing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using row_number() but you need to change the order by in the row_number window function to what ever determines the order of your data.

**NOTE THIS UPDATES YOUR SOURCE TABLE**

```
alter yourTable
add column New_Code int

;with cte as(
    select
        ID
         ,New_Code = row_number() over (partition by Subject_code, Start, Organizer order by (select null)) 
         --the order by here likely needs to be changed to what determines the order of your data
        ,Subject_code
        ,Start
        ,Organizer
        ,status
    from
        yourTable)

update cte
set New_Code = case when New_Code = 1 then 1 else 0 end

select 
    *
from 
    yourTable
```

Comment: This is perfect solution for the problem.

Comment: glad to help @Sam